# After clicking on ancor tag, jQuery mouseover won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote some jQuery so that when the mouse enters an area jQuery removes a display: hide; property.

It works when the page is first loaded, however, when one of the anchor tags is clicked, it in the element that was unhidden, the mouse opens the menu, but doesn't stay open once the mouse is moved over the menu.

How do I fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#kDropdown, .hidden-dropdown .row .columns').bind('mouseenter', function(e) {
    $(".hidden-dropdown").removeClass("hide");
  });
  $('#kDropdown, .hidden-dropdown .row .columns').bind('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.hidden-dropdown').addClass("hide");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden-dropdown hide">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
      <ul style="position: relative; float: left;">
        <li><a href="#">Motion Sensor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Water Detector</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Smart Plug</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Door Sensor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Door Sensor Pro</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul style="position: relative; float: right;">
        <li><a href="#">Z-Wave Extender</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Siren</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mouser</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Water Valve</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <!-- Trigger to open-->
    <div class="hidden-dropdown hide">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
          <ul style="position: relative; float: left;">
            <li><a href="#">Motion Sensor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Water Detector</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Smart Plug</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Door Sensor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Door Sensor Pro</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul style="position: relative; float: right;">
            <li><a href="#">Z-Wave Extender</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Siren</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mouser</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Water Valve</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example is incomplete. Assuming your `hide` css class is `display: none;` NOTHING is rendered in your example because everything has the hide class.

Comment: The .hide class is display: none; The jquery I have does render it. The issue is it doesn't stay.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear is correct—everything is hidden by default so there would be nothing to trigger the mouseenter event. I notice you have nested "hidden-dropdown" objects, did you perhaps mean to only hide the nested levels?

Comment: The whole thing is supposed to be hidden until the mouse enters Product tab on the nav bar snippit. Then it is supposed to act like a drop down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make the dropdown menu a child of the navigation link.**

Assuming you want the navigation/dropdowns to be like [this site](https://www.jetbrains.com/), I always use something similar to the following structure (XML):

```
<navigation>
  <link position="relative" height="30px">
    <text>About Us</text>
    <dropdown position="absolute" top="30px">
      <dropdowncontent></dropdowncontent>
    </dropdown>
  </link>
  ... more links ...
</navigation>
```

See how the `dropdown` is a child of the `link`? This means that when you attach a `mouseenter` event to your `link`, hovering over the `dropdown` actually *counts* as hovering over the `link`. To edit your code (and take out some unnecessary bits):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hidden-dropdown').hide();
  $('.link').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).children('.hidden-dropdown').show();
  });
  $('.link').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).children('.hidden-dropdown').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.link {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.hidden-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">
  <p>Product</p>
  <div class="hidden-dropdown">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
        <ul style="position: relative; float: left;">
          <li><a href="#">Motion Sensor</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Water Detector</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Smart Plug</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Door Sensor</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Door Sensor Pro</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul style="position: relative; float: right;">
          <li><a href="#">Z-Wave Extender</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Siren</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mouser</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Water Valve</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```